# Why is polymer preprocessing my CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, polymer

When using Polymer with using Chrome version 34.0.1847.116 I notice that my CSS rules are being preprocessed in some way. For example:

```
background: url(...) 50% 50%;
```

becomes

```
background-image: url(...);
background-position:  50% 50%;
...
```

Is this the result of the polyfill? Is there any way around this?

Comment: The former is simply the shorthand way of declaring the latter. It's not "changing" your CSS except by writing it out completely. Like saying "thru" to mean "through", or "afk" to mean "away from keyboard".

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know the two are equivalent. I need to know why this is happening and if I can prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer processes stylesheets and `<style>` inside a `<polymer-element>` in order to shim styles for the Shadow DOM polyfill to work. Under native Shadow DOM, they won't be touched.

Polymer's shimmer uses the CSSOM to fix-up and adjust styles. I suspect what you're seeing is the result of that process.

BTW, if you know for a fact, the styles inside the sheet don't use any shadow dom features, you can add the `no-shim` attribute to tell Polymer to leave the contents alone:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="main.css" no-shim>
```

Docs:

- [Polyfill shimming details](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#polyfill-details).
- [Controlling the polyfill’s CSS shimming](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#stylingattrs)

Comment: Thank you yet again for a great Polymer answer. Exactly what I needed.